# Why is my private worker crashing on Spacelift?

Tags: terraform, spacelift

I am using a private worker on Spacelift but my run keeps failing with the error "worker crashed".

This is only happening on one stack, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common reason is that it has run out of memory.

It is worth checking the CPU and memory usage of the workers, this can happen with really big stacks that are using an [EC2 instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/US_SingleMetricPerInstance.html) (or equivalent) with not enough memory to handle it.

If you are using Terraform, you could also add the env var [TF_LOG = DEBUG](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/internals/debugging) to get more verbose logging which may give clues.

Thank you!